$\sqrt{t^2}$ and $\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$ in $\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}6}\right)\mathrm dx$
Below is a question from my class notes:

Evaluate:$$\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}6}\right)\mathrm dx$$

I substituted $x=3\cos 2\theta$ and got the answer as(Note that $\text{sgn}x$ denotes the sign/signum function.)
$$-12\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8\right)+24n\pi\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4\right)+C\text{ when }x\in[2n\pi-\pi/2, 2n\pi+\pi/2]$$ and
$$12\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8\right)-12(2n+1)\pi\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4\right)+C\text{ when }x\in[2n\pi+\pi/2, 2n\pi+3\pi/2]$$
But my teacher says  the answer is just:
$$-12\left(\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8\right)+C$$
He explained to simply take $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{1+\cos2\theta}}=\tan\theta$, $\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2}=\sin\theta$ and $\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta)=\theta$ and not take cases as this doesn't matter for indefinite integrals, but I don't understand why. Please help me wrap my head around this.
My attempt:
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}6}\right)\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{1+\cos2\theta}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2}\right)\mathrm -6\sin2\theta d\theta$$
$$=-12\text{sgn}(\tan\theta)\int \sin^2\theta\sin^{-1}\left(\text{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin\theta\right)\mathrm  d\theta$$
Now, I used:
$$x\in[2n\pi-\pi/2, 2n\pi+\pi/2]\implies \sin^{-1}(\sin x)=x-2n\pi\tag{Case 1}$$
$$x\in[2n\pi+\pi/2, 2n\pi+3\pi/2]\implies \sin^{-1}(\sin x)=(2n+1)\pi-x\tag{Case 2}$$
And since
$$\int \sin^2\theta d\theta=\int\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2 d\theta=\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4+C$$
$$\int \theta\sin^2\theta d\theta=\theta\left(\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4\right)-\int\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4 d\theta=\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8+C$$
I got

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $$\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}6}\right)\mathrm dx$$
$$=-12\text{sgn}(\tan\theta)\int \sin^2\theta(\text{sgn}(\sin\theta)\theta-2n\pi)\mathrm  d\theta$$
$$=-12\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8\right)+24n\pi\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4\right)+C$$

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ $$\int \sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}6}\right)\mathrm dx$$
$$=-12\text{sgn}(\tan\theta)\int \sin^2\theta((2n+1)\pi-\text{sgn}(\sin\theta)\theta)\mathrm  d\theta$$
$$=12\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta^2}4-\frac{\theta\sin2\theta}4-\frac{\cos2\theta}8\right)-12(2n+1)\pi\text{sgn}(\cos\theta)\left(\frac{\theta}2-\frac{\sin2\theta}4\right)+C$$



This is not an answer to the question.
Instead, this is a long-winded comment:

He explained to simply take ...$~\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta)=\theta~$ and not take cases as this doesn't matter for indefinite integrals...

The range of the Arcsin function is arbitrarily set to $~[-\pi/2,\pi/2].~$  Therefore, the excerpted equation will hold if and only if $~-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2.~$
So, your teacher is flat wrong, but (assuming that this is a high school class), probably very well intentioned.
In high school, the Calculus-teaching is generally geared towards problem solving, rather than valid analysis.  Allowing subtly invalid analysis allows the teacher to familiarize the high school students with Calculus problems to solve that don't require an in depth comprehension of the underlying theorems.
This is generally a good thing, because the teacher will then limit assigned problems to a narrow range, so that invalid analysis is not relevant.
Then, in college, those students who choose to pursue Calculus will automatically have the invalid ideas corrected.  Therefore, the overall approach in high school almost certainly does more good than harm.

Yes, I am in high school. But if this is a long-winded comment, why did you decide to post it as an answer?

@MathGuy For one thing, posting this response as a series of comments would have made this response more difficult to comprehend.  For another, creating such a series of comments creates comment-clutter, which should generally be avoided on MathSE.

+1 although I disagree about this not qualifying as an answer. The remark on $\arcsin$'s domain addresses the question perfectly.

I figured out that my solution is incomplete and my teacher’s final answer is correct, although the details(of a bijective substitution) were overlooked. I missed out stating the domain of $\theta$ for the substitution to be bijective so that back-substitution is possible.
The domain of $x$ is $(-3,3]$, so for $x=3\cos2\theta$, the best choice is to let $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$ as $\sin\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are both positive and we can say $\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta)=\theta$ as $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)\subset\left[\frac{-\pi}2,\frac\pi2\right]$. This means that
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2}=\sin\theta$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{1+\cos2\theta}}=\tan\theta$$
which now removes any need for the $\text{sgn}$ function.
